# Javascript - can't modify/change var object value inside function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Javascript - can't modify/change var object value inside function?

```
var shared = {
        lock: true,
        connection: '',
        messages: []
    };

Socket.onopen = function(e)
    {
        shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';
        shared.lock = false;
    };
```

Something like this, and it doesn't work.

But code is proper, because something like this

```
shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';
Socket.onopen = function(e)
        {
            shared.lock = false;
        };
```

does work.

so It's like I can't modify shared.connection inside this function...

But what's strange

Socket.onerror = function(e)
{
    shared.messages.push(generateMessage('System', 'Wystąpił błąd! Połączenie zostało przerwane.', 'others'));
    shared.lock = true;
};

This one works, pushes properly message to `messages` array in `shared`.

What's up? What is going on?

How to get it work?

Full code:

```
<script>

    var shared = {
        lock: true,
        connection: '',
        messages: []
    };

    function generateMessage(nick = '', content = '', color = '')
    {
        return {
            time: timeNow(),
            nick: nick,
            content: content,
            color: color
        };
    }

    function timeNow()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        return date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    }

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                lock: shared.lock,
                connection: shared.connection,
                login: true,
                message: {
                    time: '',
                    nick: '',
                    content: '',
                    color: 'others'
                },
                messages: shared.messages
            }
        },
        methods:
        {
            submit: function()
            {
                var date = new Date();
                this.message.time = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
                Socket.send(JSON.stringify(this.message));
                this.message.color = '';
                this.messages.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.message)));
                this.login = false;
                this.message.color = 'others';
                this.message.content = '';
            }
        }
    }

    var Socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/chat');

    Socket.onopen = function(e)
    {
        shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';
        console.log(shared.connection);
        shared.lock = false;
    };

    Socket.onmessage = function(e)
    {
        shared.messages.push(JSON.parse(e.data));
    };

    Socket.onerror = function(e)
    {
        shared.messages.push(generateMessage('System', 'Wystąpił błąd! Połączenie zostało przerwane.', 'others'));
        shared.lock = true;
    };

    Socket.onclose = function(e)
    {
        shared.messages.push(generateMessage('System', 'Połączenie zostało zamknięte.', 'others'));
        shared.lock = true;
    };


</script>
```

This question is different because we are facing here VueJS which comes with reactivity and var value can be changed in the future.

```
Socket.onopen = function(e)
    {
        shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';
        shared.messages.push(generateMessage('System', 'Wystąpił błąd! Połączenie zostało przerwane.', 'others'));
```

`shared.messages.push(generateMessage('System', 'Wystąpił błąd! Połączenie zostało przerwane.', 'others'));` this one works good, messages in Vue updates and I can see it,

but `shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';` doesn't work, nothing updates in vue... What is going on ? :/

It updates the value, but Vue doesn't get it.

I think it is something with vue..

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're not showing any code that would give you an indication that `shared` is not being modified. Probably an async issue, but still can't tell without a full demo.

Comment: That is just it, nothing else modifies shared.connection and as you can see putting this before this function works @llama

Comment: Sure, but what makes you think it's not modified? Only way to tell would be to try to examine your mutations somewhere, but you're not showing that.

Comment: You're code seems to work fine, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @llama I am sure because it is the only line of code that modifies that and because even putting it before function works, it's just something bad about being this inside this function

Comment: I'll try one more time. You're assigning some values to the object properties. We get that. But for some reason you've gotten the idea that the values didn't actually get assigned. What is giving you that idea? Nothing in your example would indicate a post-mutation examination of the object that would lead you to the conclusion you reached.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/jubogic/edit?js,console

Comment: I think it doesn't modify the value, I changed to `xxx` for initial, `connection: 'xxx',` and after onopen nothing changes. but onopen works, tried even `console.log('aaa");` inside onopen

Comment: Surely the `console.log(shared.connection);` right after `shared.connection = 'Zostałeś połączony pomyślnie!';` does log the expected value, doesn't it? I bet the one that's "not modified" is one of the results of calling `data()`, right?

Comment: Some other things to improve: you're using ES6 module syntax inside a `<script>`, how does that work? And you'd better use multiple named exports instead of one object literal default export.

Comment: @Bergi using Laravel-Mix (so webpack)

Comment: @Bergi yes right about this `data()`

Comment: @Bergi please come here mate :D

Comment: @Bergi please help me :  /

Comment: Have you understood the problem that was described in the duplicate question?

Comment: @Bergi I think I have understood, but I use Vue here, reactivity is here. And it worked well before I seperated this in component file, before I have one big file inline in php front-end. I have read whole duplicate you assigned and I tried some things, but didn't work + I don't think it is about this especially due to Vue

Comment: Can you post the working code and the full separated-component non-working code, please?